# Angular6 CLI bundle JavaScript to a single file (Ionic)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-cli, angular6, ionic4

I'm unable to force Angular output to a single file using the Angular 6 CLI.

Our production build always produces ~100 chunks.

We are using the router module without lazy loading (since our application is rather small we'd prefer a single output file).

Is there any way to force that?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomePage },
  { path: 'test/:id/', component: TestPage }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Angular CLI config:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "defaultProject": "app",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "progress": false,
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/ionic/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/global.scss"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ionic/schematics-angular"
  }
}
```